# Gaussian conditional probability $X$ given $X+Y$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Gaussian random variables with means $\mu_1 = 1$ and $\mu_2 = 0$ and variances $\sigma^2_1 = 1$ and $\sigma^2_2 = 1$ respectively. How to find the conditional density of $X$ given $X+Y = 2$: $\mathbf{P}(X|X+Y = 2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following I am abusing notation slightly. I write $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ instead of $p_X(x)$ etc.

Recall that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x|X+Y=2)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=x,X+Y=2)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=2)}.
$$
Now by independence,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x,X+Y=2) = \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=2-x) = \mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=2-x).
$$
For the denominator, recall that for independent, normally random variables,
$$
X+Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1² + \sigma_2²).
$$
Put everything together to get

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X=x|X+Y=2) &= \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-1)^{2}}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(2-x)^{2}}{2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{2}} e^{-\frac{(2-1)^{2}}{4}}} \\\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2+3x-\frac{9}{4}} \\\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-(x-\frac{3}{2})^{2}},
\end{align*}
which means that
$$
X | (X+Y=2) \sim \mathcal{N}\bigg(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigg).
$$

Comment: Could you kindly write out P(Y=2-X).

Comment: Note that $x$ is a fixed value and not the random variable $X$. More specifically, $x$ is the argument at which you want to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(X|X+Y=2)$. So you want to compute $\mathbb{P}(Y=2-x)$ and NOT $\mathbb{P}(Y=2-X)$.

Comment: Yes saw it after the edit button went off. Can you please write it down explicitly?

Comment: Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862551/compute-ex-mid-xy-if-x-y-is-centered-normal-with-known-covariance-matri/1862564#1862564), and let me know if the formulation there is incorrect, please.

Comment: It's $\mathbb{P}(Y=2-x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_2}e^{-\frac{(2-x-\mu_2)²}{2\sigma_2²}}.$

Comment: Thats what I thought, it does not match with the value. Not sure your formulation is correct or there is a typo. I have updated the original question. The answer given in the slide in my class is 1.5 for the mean and 0.5 for variance.

Comment: If you do the math, it is exactly what you get with what I have written. :)

Comment: I have added the calculation to my answer.

Comment: I was making an error, thanks a lot!